# Almacenar valor de variables al volver a cargar un Windows Form

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms

Buen día,

estoy desarrollando una aplicación en C# utilizando Windows Forms y controles de usuario, la aplicación que estoy desarrollando es un proyecto pequeño para un restaurante el cual en la interfaz de mesas, lo que hace es al dar clic en la mesa correspondiente cambia su estado ya sea "ocupado" o "disponible". Lo que pasa es que al cambiar de Form y al volver al de las mesas todos vuelven a "disponible".

Hay alguna forma de que se puedan guardar los cambios y no se vuelvan a default al momento de que salga y vuelva a entrar al Form de mesas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Solamente las guardo como variables globales:

```
class variables
{
    public static bool presionado ;
    public static bool presionado2 ;
    public static bool presionado3;
    public static bool presionado4;
    public static bool presionado5 ;
    public static bool presionado6 ;
    public static bool presionado7 ;
    public static bool presionado8 ;
    public static bool presionado9 ;
    public static bool presionado10 ;
    public static bool presionado11 ;
    public static bool presionado12 ;
}
```

Dentro de Form Mesas:

```
if(variables.presionado == false)
{
    button1.BackColor = Color.Gold;
    variables.presionado = true;
}
else
{
    button1.BackColor = Color.Green;
    variables.presionado = false;
}
```

Comment: ¿Cómo está guardando el estado? Por favor, [edit] y agregue el código en su pregunta.

Comment: Lo estoy guardando simplemente con variables globales. Saludos.

Comment: *Sin haber visto su código* mi sugerencia es: guardar el estado "directamente en la base de datos - columna de tipo boolean".

Comment: No uses variables globales nunca. Lo que debes hacer es almacenar el estado de las mesas (base de datos, json....) y recuperarlo al cargar el formulario de nuevo. Que pasa si te cambian de formulario y cierran la aplicación? Todos los cambios que se hayan hecho en ese se perderán.

Comment: Muchas Gracias amigos, tenían razón termine usando base de datos saludos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yo hice la prueba, y me funciono usando una **Lista estática** y referenciando todos los botones a **button_Click**, también obtuve todos los controles del formulario y los guarde en una lista donde la voy a recorrer y preguntar si corresponde solo 
 a las **Mesas**, si son de tipo **Button** y si están en la lista de mesas **ocupadas**, debo aclarar que mientras no se cierre la aplicación va a almacenar la información pero si se llegase a cerrar por algún motivo ya no se podrá recuperar la información:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private IEnumerable<Control> ListaControles;
    private List<Button> ListaOcupados;

    public class Class1<T>
    {
        public static List<T> ListaOcupados { get; set; }
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListaControles = obtenerControles(this, typeof(Button));
        ListaOcupados = new List<Button>();
        cargarListado();
    }

    private IEnumerable<Control> obtenerControles(Control control, Type tipo)
    {
        IEnumerable<Control> controles = control.Controls.Cast<Control>();
        return controles.SelectMany(x => obtenerControles(x, tipo))
                        .Concat(controles)
                        .Where(c => c.GetType() == tipo);
    }

    private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!ListaOcupados.Any(x => x.Name == ((Button)sender).Name))
            ListaOcupados.Add((Button)sender);
        else
            ListaOcupados.RemoveAll(x => x.Name == ((Button)sender).Name);
        Class1<Button>.ListaOcupados = ListaOcupados;
        cargarListado();
    }

    private void cargarListado()
    {
        if (Class1<Button>.ListaOcupados != null)
        {
            if (Class1<Button>.ListaOcupados.Count > 0)
                ListaOcupados = Class1<Button>.ListaOcupados;
        }
        foreach (Control control in ListaControles)
        {
            if (control.GetType() == typeof(Button) && control.Text.Contains("Mesa"))
            {
                if (ListaOcupados.Any(x => x.Name == control.Name))
                    control.BackColor = Color.Red;
                else
                    control.BackColor = Color.Green;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias Víctor, solo la cuestión es: ¿Como puedo regresar al color original al presionar de nueva cuenta el botón?.

Comment: Removiendo de la lista y recorriendola si esta en la lista lo pintas del color de ocupado y si no esta lo pintas del color que no esta ocupado. Ve que yo estoy recorriendo los controles que hay en el formulario y preguntando si existe o no en la lista para pintarlos, aparte necesariamente tienen que ser de tipo Button adicionalmente puedes agregar otra condición para que solo sean los botones de la mesa y no otros botones que puedan haber en tu formulario.

Comment: ¡Muchas Gracias Victor!

Comment: De nada amigo si te sirvió valida la pregunta como buena

Answer (score 0):

Al almacenar la informacion en variables, cuando se cierre la app por alguna razon al no estar persistidas se perderan.
Para persistir datos tienes muchas opciones, desde base de datos hasta archivos JSON, XML y txt.

*Volviendo a la pregunta.*

Lo mas seguro es que no estés implementando de manera correcta el concepto de variables globales.

Te recomiendo implementar el patrón **singleton**, donde tienes una clase la cual tiene una única instancia y podrías acceder a esa instancia globalmente.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-ar/library/bb972272.aspx

> Aplicabilidad
>
> Usar cuando:
>
> Deba haber exactamente una instancia de una clase y ésta deba ser
>   accesible a los clientes desde un punto de acceso conocido.
>
> La única instancia debería ser extensible mediante herencia y los
>   clientes deberían ser capaces de utilizar una instancia extendida sin
>   modificar su código.

```
public class MesasPresionadas
{
    private static MesasPresionadas data;

    private MesasPresionadas()
    {
    }

    public static MesasPresionadas Instance()
    {
        if (data == null)
            data = new MesasPresionadas(); 
        return data;
    }

    public bool presionado{ get; set; }
    public bool presionado2{ get; set; }
    public bool presionado3{ get; set; }
    public bool presionado4{ get; set; }
    public bool presionado5{ get; set; }
    public bool presionado6{ get; set; }
    public bool presionado7{ get; set; }
    public bool presionado8{ get; set; }
    public bool presionado9{ get; set; }
    public bool presionado10{ get; set; }
    public bool presionado11{ get; set; }
    public bool presionado12{ get; set; }
}
```

Y la forma de acceder a los datos desde cualquier punto seria

```
if (MesasPresionadas.Instance().presionado  == false)
{
    button1.BackColor = Color.Gold;
    MesasPresionadas.Instance().presionado = true;
}
else
{
    button1.BackColor = Color.Green;
    MesasPresionadas.Instance().presionado  = false;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Con la clase *IsolatedStorageFile* puedes crear unos ficheros virtuales a los cuales sólo tu aplicación tendrá acceso y sólo serán visibles por esta. Podrías usarlo para guardar información del último estado de tu aplicación y sus variables. Echa un ojo a este [enlace](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-read-and-write-to-files-in-isolated-storage) donde viene un ejemplo de uso.

Edito: Yo lo suelo utilizar para almacenar información como el nombre del último usuario que accedió o incluso su contraseña. La lectura y escritura en el fichero es como la que se hace con un fichero ordinario.

Editado 2:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.IsolatedStorage;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IsolatedStorageFile isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetStore(IsolatedStorageScope.User | IsolatedStorageScope.Assembly, null, null);

            if (isoStore.FileExists("TestStore.txt"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The file already exists!");
                using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isoStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("TestStore.txt", FileMode.Open, isoStore))
                {
                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(isoStream))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Reading contents:");
                        Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isoStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("TestStore.txt", FileMode.CreateNew, isoStore))
                {
                    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(isoStream))
                    {
                        writer.WriteLine("Hello Isolated Storage");
                        Console.WriteLine("You have written to the file.");
                    }
                }
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

Espero que te sirva. Saludos.

Comment: ¿Podrías escribir el código con lo que planteas? ya sabes, los enlaces podrían caducar.